# Serializing a list of dynamic objects to a CSV with ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#, csv, servicestack, servicestack-text

All of my EF classes have a `Projection()` method that helps me choose what I want to project from the class to the SQL queries:

Example:

```
    public static Expression<Func<Something, dynamic>> Projection()
    {
        return e => new
        {
            something = e.SomethingId,
            name = e.Name,
            requiredThingId = e.RequiredThingId,
            requiredThing = new
            {
                requiredThingId = e.RequiredThing.RequiredThingId,
                name = e.RequiredThing.Name,
                ...
            },
            optionalThingId = e.OptionalThingId,
            optionalThing = e.OptionalThingId == null ? null : new 
            {
                optionalThingId = e.OptionalThing.OptionalThingId,
                name = e.OptionalThing.Name
            }
            ...
        };
    }
```

I use these projection methods like this:

```
  List<dynamic> projected = dbContext.Something.Select(Something.Projection()).ToList();
```

This way lets me reuse my projections all around my project.

I want to use **ServiceStack.Text** to serialize these lists to CSV.

I'm doing this:

```
 string csvString = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv<dynamic>(Something.Select(Something.Projection()).ToList());

 byte[] csvBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(csvString);

 return File(csvBytes, "text/csv", "foo.csv");
```

But the result is an empty csv (csvString is full of "\r\n"'s and nothing more)

Questions:

- Am I using correctly the `SerializeToCsv()` method?
- Can I use `<dynamic>` in this library?
- Suggestions for achieving my purpose?

For the example above the desired CSV would flatten all the properties, something like:

```
  "somethingId";"name";"requiredThingId";"requiredThing.requiredThingId";"requiredThing.name";"optionalThingId";"optionalThing.optionalThingId";"optionalThing.name"
```

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my own questions, but will not mark as accepted in hope of a new greater answer..

> Am I using correctly the SerializeToCsv() method? Can I use dynamic
>   in this library?

Answer: Yes to both but ServiceStack.Text v4.0.36 is needed (which is available at MyGet, not Nuget)

> Suggestions for achieving my purpose?

Answer: With `ServiceStack.Text` it is possible to serialize to CSV a `List<dynamic>`, but all the nested properties will be rendered as JSON and they will not be flattened out, eg:

```
   List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
   list.Add(new
   {
         name = "john", 
         pet = new 
         { 
              name = "doggy"
         }
   });

   string csv = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(list);
```

This list will be serialized to this csv:

> name, pet
>   "john", { name = "doggy" }

And not to this csv, as I was expecting:

> name, pet_name
>   "john", "doggy"

So... I finally ended up writing this code:

```
public class CsvHelper
{
    public static string GetCSVString(List<dynamic> inputList)
    {
        var outputList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (var item in inputList)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> outputItem = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            flatten(item, outputItem, "");

            outputList.Add(outputItem);
        }

        List<string> headers = outputList.SelectMany(t => t.Keys).Distinct().ToList();

        string csvString = ";" + string.Join(";", headers.ToArray()) + "\r\n";

        foreach (var item in outputList)
        {
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                if (item.ContainsKey(header) && item[header] != null)
                    csvString = csvString + ";" + item[header].ToString();
                else
                    csvString = csvString + ";";
            }

            csvString = csvString + "\r\n";
        }

        return csvString;
    }

    private static void flatten(dynamic item, Dictionary<string, object> outputItem, string prefix)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.Contains("AnonymousType"))
                outputItem.Add(prefix + "__" + propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(item));
            else
                flatten(propertyInfo.GetValue(item), outputItem, (prefix.Equals("") ? propertyInfo.Name : prefix + "__" + propertyInfo.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is:

1. It flattens the List, so that all the properties of the objects in the list are primitives (eg: no nested properties)
2. It creates a CSV from that flattened list.

This algorithm is O(n*m), being
n: number of items in the list
m: number of properties inside each item (including nested properties)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the recommendation is to use clean POCO's for Serialization, you can serialize in-line anonymous types, e.g:

```
var somethings =  dbContext.Something.Select(e => new { 
    something = e.SomethingId, 
    name = e.Name 
});
somethings.ToCsv().Print();
```

Otherwise I've just added support for serializing `IEnumerable<object>` and `IEnumerable<dynamic>` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/ce2e4b31403c05c8e0d2ee1ea37a9ca94e40ae80).

This change is available from **v4.0.36+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: what do you mean by "in-line anonymous types"? does it mean that the "subobjects" will not be considered? (eg. something.foo.bar.qux)

Comment: @sports I just mean [C#'s Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), the type of which is only available from within the same method, e.g. you'll lose access the schema when you return `object` or `dynamic`.

Comment: Im unable to install "4.0.36+", just 4.0.35. I tried with the package manager console with `Install-Package ServiceStack.Text -IncludePrerelease`. In 4.0.35 is not possible to serialize a anonymous type like I was doing in my original post?

Comment: @sports Please see the link in the Comment, the v4.0.36 pre-release NuGet packages are [only available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet), not to be confused with NuGet.

Comment: Ah you are right.. Well, installed 4.0.36 from MyGet but .ToCsv().Print() isn't recognized. Is it the same to use `string s = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(dbContext.Something.Select(e = new { ... }))` ?

Comment: I used SerializeToCsv and it worked, but "sub-objects" (ie: not primitives) are rendered as JSON. Is it possible to flat them to columns? Maybe it is too much to ask for the library though

Comment: @sports they're extension methods, `T.ToCsv()` is in `ServiceStack` namespace whilst `T.Print()` is in `ServiceStack.Text`. But yes it's the same as calling [CsvSerializer.SerializeToString()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/853a9ed86aabccb06c78058f007cabe7c9b0e2a0/src/ServiceStack.Text/StringExtensions.cs#L442)

Comment: @sports CSV isn't a hierarchical data format, i.e. it doesn't support nested data structures which is why their blobbed (with  JSV format). You'd need to change what you're serializing to use scalar properties if you only want a tabular CSV dataset.

Comment: Paste a hierarchical json here: https://json-csv.com/, thats what I'm looking for. Columns are like "nested1__nested__nested3"

Comment: @mythz When I try to serialize using CsvSerializer.SerializeToStream() or ToCsv() from a IEnumerable<dynamic>, it's always empty.  I'm using 4.0.42.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that part of what is going on is that **the library is using properties in the object to determine what to serialize**. I believe that a dynamic object **does not** construct properties like it's a POCO. If you don't setup a `getter` and `setter` on your object, it certainly won't work. Just for reference, I using version 4.5.6.0 of this library.